# Error while trying to do constructor injection in spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I'm new to spring framework i was trying out the example featured in the videos in java brains I ran into some problem when trying to do constructor injection the error seem to be related to finding the default constructor. the error is given below

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [test.Triangle]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test.Triangle.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at test.app.main(app.java:18)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [test.Triangle]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test.Triangle.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:70)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test.Triangle.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2721)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2002)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:65)
... 14 more
```

My XML file is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
<bean id="triangle" class="test.Triangle">
    <constructor-arg value="Right"/>
</bean>
```

Main class

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class app {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

    Triangle obj = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");

    obj.draw();
}
}
```

Triangle Class

```
package test;


public class Triangle {
private String type;
 public Triangle(String type) {        
    this.type = type;        
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
 public void draw(){
    System.out.println(getType()+" Triangle Drawn of height: ");
}
}
```

Comment: Something is triggering instantiation of the Triangle class without parameter. Are you sure the Spring Config you show is the one and only in the project?

Comment: is `spring.xml` a valid xml file? is there `</beans>` tag at the end?

Comment: Thankyou Jens Schauder that was the problem... i just copy pasted the file intially to the src folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in my case was that i had copy pasted the spring.xml in 2 locations as just for trial and forgot about it, hence the problem in creating instances. SO check if the same file is there in different locations inside the project folder.